# Android Memory Leak when drawing bitmap

Tags: android, memory, garbage-collection

i'm drawing a bitmap on a map every time the user touches the screen on a position of a map.
The bitmap is a 'picture' of the layout i created.

When i monitor the memory allocation, i see that the memory allocation keeps growing,
even after a GC...

I'm reusing the bitmap so what's wrong with the code below?

every time the user touches the screen, this method gets called and the ondraw method draws the returned overalldrawing:

```
    public Bitmap LoadBitmapFromView(RelativeLayout drawingCanvas, int width,int height)
    {
        drawingCanvas.LayoutParameters=(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width, height));
        drawingCanvas.Measure(MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec(drawingCanvas.LayoutParameters.Width, MeasureSpecMode.Exactly),
        MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec(drawingCanvas.LayoutParameters.Height, MeasureSpecMode.Exactly));
        drawingCanvas.Layout(0, 0, drawingCanvas.MeasuredWidth , drawingCanvas.MeasuredHeight);
        Bitmap overAllDrawing = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.Argb8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(overAllDrawing);
        drawingCanvas.Draw(canvas);
        return overAllDrawing;
    }


    protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas) 
    {
        base.OnDraw(canvas);

        if (!IsImageReady)
        {
            return;
        }

        PointF xMin = ViewToSourceCoord (0f,0f) ;
        PointF xMax = ViewToSourceCoord (metrics.WidthPixels, 0f);

        PointF vPin;
        float vX;
        float vY;
        foreach (Location location in locations)
        {
            if ( (location.X > xMin.X) && (location.X < xMax.X))
                //&& (location.Y > yMin.Y) && (location.Y < yMax.Y) )  slows down performance
            {   
                vPin = SourceToViewCoord (new PointF ((float)location.X, (float)location.Y));
                vX = vPin.X - (pin.Width / 2);
                vY = vPin.Y - pin.Height;
                canvas.DrawBitmap (pin, vX, vY, paint);
            }

        }
        if (sChar != null && character != null) 
        {
            //draw character
            PointF vChar = SourceToViewCoord (sChar);
            float vCharX = vChar.X;
            float vCharY = vChar.Y - character.Height;
            canvas.DrawBitmap (character, vCharX, vCharY, paint);
        }
        if (pinPushed) 
        {
            PointF vInfo = SourceToViewCoord ((float)selectedLocation.X, (float)selectedLocation.Y);
            float vInfoX = vInfo.X - (info.Width / 2) + (int)ConvertDpToPix (7);//8 pixels cause image is not in the middle
            float vInfoY = vInfo.Y - info.Height;
            canvas.DrawBitmap (textBalloonBitmap, vInfoX, vInfoY, paint);
            vInfo = null;
        }

    }
```

Comment: You say you are reusing the `Bitmap` but every time `LoadBitmapFromView(...)` is called you are actually creating a new `Bitmap` using `Bitmap overAllDrawing = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(...)` then returning a reference to it.

Comment: yeah but when i create a global variable bitmap and replace that bitmap in the method, it keeps leaking...

Comment: Are you recycling the bitmap?

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I tried recycling but i get an error that says: cannot draw a recycled bitmap

Comment: Yes sorry, I just re-read the docs for `recycle()`. It frees the native bitmap object for GC but also marks the `Bitmap` instance as 'dead' preventing it from being drawn again (as you pointed out). I'm not sure what else to suggest.

Comment: it's kinda the same problem as the one in this link http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/27801/memory-leak-in-canvas-drawbitmap  i'm also using Xamarin, maybe the garbage collection isn't as good, i'm trying with the weakreference class at the moment. hope it works :/

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?